# Open asynchronous sockets in PHP

Tags: php, sockets, asynchronous

I am writing a port scanner in PHP that supports small ranges (e.g., ports 21-25). The ports and IP to be scanned are sent to the server via AJAX, and then PHP attempts to open a socket on each of the ports. If it succeeds, the port is open, if it times out, the port is closed.

Currently, despite sending all of the AJAX requests at the same time for ports 21-25, each socket is only opened after the last one closes. So, port 21 is checked, the socket is closed, and then port 22 is checked, and so on. What I want is for all ports to be checked concurrently, so I'd be opening several sockets at once.

I've tried:

```
$fp = @fsockopen($ip,$port,$errno,$errstr,2);
socket_set_nonblock($fp);
```

But this doesn't work, as I'm setting non-block AFTER the socket has already been opened and is waiting for a response. Is what I'm trying to do possible in PHP?

Comment: Please give us the behavior you're seeing.  How do you know it's not working?  Please provide the code you're running after creating the socket.  What you've provided is correct, so if there's a problem, it's probably in the code afterwards.  The code you've provided doesn't show anything that is "waiting for a response".  Also, it is fine to set nonblocking (or setting it back to blocking) after created -- Pretty sure there's no other way.

Comment: @xaxxon This works fine for sockets that are intended to stay open, but I'm just writing a port scanner, so it opens a socket, then closes it as soon as the connection is established. I'm just verifying that creating a socket using that IP and port is possible, essentially. The problem is that the socket_set_nonblock() doesn't take effect during the 2-second timeout window, so if a port isn't open on the target, it will wait the full two seconds before trying the next socket. **In other words**, the timeout window is blocking other sockets from being made.

Comment: I see.  Since fsockopen doesn't return until the socket has successfully connected, your call to make it nonblocking doesn't get called until after the connection has either completed or failed.  @pleasestand 's answer looks good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use different functions: [`socket_create()`](http://php.net/socket_create) and [`socket_connect()`](http://php.net/socket_connect) instead of `fsockopen()`. This works:

```
$socks = array();
for ($port = 21; $port <= 25; $port++) {
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_nonblock($sock);
    @socket_connect($sock, 'localhost', $port);
    $socks[$port] = $sock;
}

$startTime = microtime(true);
while ($socks && microtime(true) - $startTime < 3) {
    $null = null;
    $write = $socks;
    socket_select($null, $write, $null, 1);
    foreach ($write as $port => $sock) {
        $desc = "$port/tcp";
        $errno = socket_get_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR);

        if ($errno == 0) {
            echo "$desc open\n";
        } elseif ($errno == SOCKET_ECONNREFUSED) {
            echo "$desc closed\n";
        } elseif ($errno == SOCKET_ETIMEDOUT) {
            echo "$desc filtered\n";
        } else {
            $errmsg = socket_strerror($errno);
            echo "$desc error $errmsg\n";
        }

        unset($socks[$port]);
        socket_close($sock);
    }
}

foreach ($socks as $port => $sock) {
    $desc = "$port/tcp";
    echo "$desc filtered\n";
    socket_close($sock);
}
```